# WPF - example of creating XPS document that is NOT from Visual

Tags: wpf, xps, documentviewer

I'm looking for a reporting/printing solution that does not involve RDLC/SSRS. I'd like to use the DocumentViewer, which I know supports XPS. I have found plenty of examples that use Visual to XPS but I haven't found many examples where I can take an existing WPF page, with various controls like labels, listboxes, grids, etc and create that into an XPS document. Is there a code example out there that takes an entire XAML page and creates XPS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not trivial, the basic problem here is that XPS represent fixed pages. An existing WPF page does not necessarily translate to pages on a document. How will your report be split if it cannot fit the page? This information is needed.

What you can do is to create the report as a FlowDocument (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx). This will give the .NET framework enough info on how to paginate your report such that when you do this:

```
FlowDocument flowDocument;

// load, populate your flowDocument here

XpsDocument xpsDocument = new XpsDocument("filename.xps", FileAccess.ReadWrite);
XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDocument);
writer.Write(((IDocumentPaginatorSource)flowDocument).DocumentPaginator);
```

it works.  (Code lifted from Pro WPF in C# Book).

Answer (score 1):

Usually your WPF page has a root UI element, say Grid. As Grid is a specific type of Visual(please vide "Inheritance Hierarchy" part @http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx for more details), you just need to write that root Grid element like other visuals into XPS. And then all embedded controls will be automatically written into XPS document.